# python error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type

Tags: python, sqlite, xbmc

I'm working on my python script using the version 2.6 for XBMC media application.

I have got a problem with my python script, I'm getting an error:  Error Contents: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.

The error are jumping on this line:

```
cur.execute('SELECT * FROM programs WHERE channel=? AND start_date <= ? AND stop_date >= ?', [channel, now, now])
```

Here is the code:

```
import xbmc
import xbmcgui
import xbmcaddon
import os
import urllib2
import StringIO
import sqlite3
from sqlite3 import dbapi2 as database
from xml.etree import ElementTree
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from UserDict import DictMixin
import datetime
import time

class MyClass(xbmcgui.WindowXML):

    def onAction(self, action):

        #DOWNLOAD THE XML SOURCE HERE
        url = ADDON.getSetting('allchannels.url')
        req = urllib2.Request(url)
        response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
        data = response.read()
        response.close()
        profilePath = xbmc.translatePath(os.path.join('special://userdata/addon_data/script.tvguide', ''))

        if os.path.exists(profilePath):
           profilePath = profilePath + 'source.db'
           con = database.connect(profilePath)
           cur = con.cursor()
           cur.execute('CREATE TABLE programs(channel TEXT, title TEXT, start_date TIMESTAMP, stop_date TIMESTAMP, description TEXT)')
           con.commit()
           con.close
           tv_elem = ElementTree.parse(StringIO.StringIO(data)).getroot()
           profilePath = xbmc.translatePath(os.path.join('special://userdata/addon_data/script.tvguide', ''))
           profilePath = profilePath + 'source.db'
           con = sqlite3.connect(profilePath)
           cur = con.cursor()
           channels = OrderedDict()

           # Get the loaded data
           for channel in tv_elem.findall('channel'):
           channel_name = channel.find('display-name').text
           for program in channel.findall('programme'):
               title = program.find('title').text
               start_time = program.get("start")
               stop_time = program.get("stop")
               cur.execute("INSERT INTO programs(channel, title, start_date, stop_date)" + " VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)", [channel_name, title, start_time, stop_time])
               con.commit()
               print 'Channels store into database are now successfully!'


           program = None
           now = datetime.datetime.now()
           #strCh = '(\'' + '\',\''.join(channelMap.keys()) + '\')'
           cur.execute('SELECT * FROM programs WHERE channel=? AND start_date <= ? AND stop_date >= ?', [channel, now, now])
           row = cur.fetchone()
           if row:
              programming = program(row['channel'], row['title'], row['start_date'], row['stop_date'])
              cur.close()
```

Here is the xbmc log:

```
- NOTE: IGNORING THIS CAN LEAD TO MEMORY LEAKS!
Error Type: <class 'sqlite3.InterfaceError'>
Error Contents: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\XBMC\addons\script.tvguide\test.py", line 1682, in onAction
cur.execute('SELECT * FROM programs WHERE channel=? AND start_date <= ? AND stop_date >= ?', [channel, now, now])
InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.
-->End of Python script error report<--
```

Comment: And what is the type of `channel`?

Comment: @CL. there are no of `channel`. I want to find the channel in a sqlite database. Can you help?

Comment: @CL. Do you have any idea?

Comment: You did not answer my question. What is `type(channel)`?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
cur.execute('SELECT * FROM programs WHERE channel=? AND start_date <= ? AND stop_date >= ?', [channel, now, now])
```

Try this:

```
inq='SELECT * FROM programs WHERE channel=' + str(channel) + ' AND ' start_date <=' + str(now) + ' AND stop_date >= ' + str(now)

cur.execute (inq)
```

Comment: This is generally a bad idea. Depending on where the value of `channel` comes from, this could lead to [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. Instead, [parameterized queries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) are preferred as @MartijnPieters is already doing.